# Three.js | How to use object's child's property outside loader.load

Tags: javascript, three.js

I need to update the object's color property dynamically using dat.GUI().
It was simple if the object is created using three.js geometry but as I'm working on an imported object (.obj & .mtl), I need to update the property outside the loader.load function.
How can I achieve it?

edit:

```
var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
mtlLoader.setPath( 'obj/Cube/' ); 
mtlLoader.load( 'cube.mtl', function( materials ) {
materials.preload();

    var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
    objLoader.setMaterials( materials );
    objLoader.setPath( 'obj/Cube/' );
    objLoader.load( 'cube.obj', function( object ) {
        object.traverse( function( child ) { 
            if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) { 
                child.castShadow = true;
                child.material.color.set( 0x00ff00 );  // change color without dat.GUI
            } 
        } );
    companion = object;
    scene.add( object );
    });
});

gui = new dat.GUI();

parameters = 
{   
    color: "#ff0000",
    visible: true,
};

var objColor = gui.addColor( parameters, 'color' ).name('Color (Diffuse)').listen();
objColor.onChange(function(value) // onFinishChange
{   companion.material.color.setHex( value.replace("#", "0x") );   });

gui.open();
updateColor(companion);
```

---

```
function updateColor(obj)
{
    obj.material.color.setHex( parameters.color.replace("#", "0x") ); //I need to use the property here.
}
```

Comment: It's better to show the code of what you've already tried.

Comment: @prisoner849 I've added the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this? -

```
objColor.onChange(function(value) // onFinishChange
{
    companion.traverse( function( child ) { 
        if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) { 
            child.material.color.setHex(value.replace("#", "0x"));
            child.material.needsUpdate = true;
        } 
    } );   
});
```

Comment: Thank You, it worked.
I wasn't sure about     companion.traverse will work outside loader.load .

Comment: You can select it as correct answer by clicking the grey tick button if it solves your problem.

Comment: Do NOT set `material.needsUpdate` when updating only the color. https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/introduction/How-to-update-things. Also, call `value.replace()` only once -- not for every mesh instance.